# Append column to pandas DataFrame without mutating the original

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When we need add a column to a DataFrame often we write:

```
df['newcol'] = 123
```

This changes (mutates) the original df object, which is not always desired.

What would be a fast and idiomatic way to do it? Here's one option, but it is about 10 slower than the above assignment.

```
df2 = concat([df, DataFrame(123, index=df.index, columns=['newcol'])], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df2 = df.assign(newcol=123)
```

Comment: Does it copy the `df` data in memory as `.copy()` does? Or it creates a *view* of original like filters do?

Answer (score 9):

what about [copy()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2['newcol'] = 123
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll take this because there are no other answers, but I was hoping there was a better way.